# How to add Editors to whole sheet protection for specific tabs?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I'm trying to find an alternative to what I'm doing manually right now, it's quite exhausting (109 spreadsheets each containing many tabs), and that is to give permission to edit specific tabs for specific Editors (with whom the whole spreadsheet has been shared with) using a script.

I have a spreadsheet with the tabs (A,B,C,D,....), these tabs contains many protected ranges (e.g. A!1:2) and should remain protected for all except myself. However, each tab has also a (whole) sheet protection where I would select (manually) the user who is allow to edit within that tab (which was a trick that I found here to prevent many Editors of the same spreadsheet to be able to edit tabs that are protected).

[Spreadsheet Demo](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/199wstlB1u8hFUkl1WcnoPb8tlsrNZGN7V5oBgZWTH9Y/edit?usp=sharing)

Using a script:
Is it possible to have a Sheet setup where I would input the emails of the current editors in a certain order (for example a column containing the names of the tabs and next to them the emails of the ones who are allowed to edit them) ?

**ADDED THE FOLLOWING SCRIPT**

```
function SetProtection() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  //removes sheet protection
var protections = ss.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.SHEET);
for (var i = 0; i < protections.length; i++) {
var protection = protections[i];
if (protection.canEdit()) {
 protection.remove();
}
}

var sh7 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
var protection = sh7.protect().setDescription('Whole Sheet Protected');  
//protects whole sheet
protection.addEditors(['test@gmail.com']); 
  }
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Yep, you can use data from a source to perform some other operation on a resource you own with a script. Nope, we aren't gonna write a script that does this for you. Yes, if you show your effort and ask a question about a specific issue in your script, we'll help to resolve it. Start simple with your script - read from a spreadsheet. Then work out how you can access the other workbooks / sheets you need to manipulate. And so on.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, the best I can do usually is to find scripts that I try to modify or get some help with since I don't know much about coding. I did search a lot, I'll continue trying to find a starting point for this issue. Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about the difference between the title of your question and ``Using a script:``?

Comment: @Nabnub Can you update your question by including the script you attempted? By this, a lot of users including me can think of about your issues.

Comment: I've updated my question and included a starting script which allows me for a specific sheet to add a particular editor. But how could I setup the process with a Setup Sheet as shown in the Spreadsheet Demo ? Thank you if you can help me with this.

Comment: @Nabnub Thank you for updating your question. In order to understand correctly the result you expect, can I ask you about it? 1. Do you want to remove the sheet protection by the sheet name and email address in a sheet of "Setup_Protection"? 2. What is the script of ``//SHEET1`` in your added script? 3. What means is this ``how could I setup the process with a Setup Sheet as shown in the Spreadsheet Demo ?``? 4. Can you provide a sample of the input and output you want? I'm really sorry for my poor English skill.

Comment: @Tanaike Thanks a lot for taking some time for this. Your English is excellent don't worry!! I've added few descriptions in the Setup_Protection Sheet if you can refer to it. Please let me know if I'm clear with my goal. Thanks a lot

Comment: @Nabnub Thank you for replying. Although I wanted to try to resolve the issue, I couldn't understand what you want to do. I'm really sorry for my poor English skill.

Comment: @Tanaike Can you have a look at my script attached to the Spreadsheet called (G+ SpreadsheetProtections): MY GOAL, in few words: a group of teachers will receive a notification to access the Spreadsheet with EDIT permission (shared ONLY with them manually or through a script if possible), HOWEVER they will be allowed to edit specific tabs only according to the Setup Sheet. Does this help you ?

Comment: I couldn't understand what you want to do. I'm really sorry for my poor skill.

Comment: I'm glad your issue was solved. But I'm sorry I couldn't help about this.

Comment: @Tanaike what we've been doing works perfectly, but I was wondering if we could do something for the following: those emails that I add in the Setup Sheet will be able to edit only if the document has been shared with them beforehand. Can we add a line of code so that the script give them also access to the whole document (i.e. add to the collaborators of the document) or even remove them is they're not listed anymore in the Setup Sheet) ?

Comment: PS: the script fires on edit, if the above could be added ☝️ , can we also pause the script for 1 or 2 min to give the time to add, remove or modify the different access permissions accordingly in the Setup Sheet? maybe using (SpreadsheetApp.flush(); or Utilities.sleep(60000) ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a lot of help, I got it work as wanted, here is the main code:

Special thanks to RENO BLAIR for his tremendous help, and anyone else who tried to help as well (@Tanaike ++)

I share the code, maybe it can be beneficial for some people:

**Notes:**

- The script fires as soon you edit the Setup_Protection sheet
- If you do not mention some of the tabs in the Setup Sheet, by default it will be protected them
- if you list them but you leave the cell next to it without email, the script will start to run and will stop at the tab where no email es mentioned.

**CODE.gs**

```
var environment = {
protectionConfigSheetName: "Setup_Protection",
};

// Script fires when the Setup_Protection SHEET is edited

function onEdit(e) {
if (e.range.getSheet().getName() === environment.protectionConfigSheetName) resetSpreadsheetProtections();
}



function removeSpreadsheetProtections(spreadsheet) {
    [
        SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.SHEET,
                                           //SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.RANGE,   // I don't want to remove the Range Protections that I will set up in each tab
    ].forEach(function (type) {
        return spreadsheet.getProtections(type).forEach(function (protection) { return protection.remove(); });
    });
}

  function getProtectionConfig(spreadsheet) {

      var protectionConfigSheetName = "Setup_Protection";
      var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(environment.protectionConfigSheetName); 

      var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
      var protectionConfig = values
          .slice(1)
          .reduce(function (protectionConfig, _a) {
          var targetSheetName = _a[0], emailAddress = _a[1];
          var config = protectionConfig.find(function (_a) {
              var sheetName = _a.sheetName;
              return sheetName === targetSheetName;
          });
          var editors = emailAddress.split(",");
          if (config)
              config.editors = config.editors.concat(editors);
          else
              protectionConfig.push({
                  sheetName: targetSheetName,
                  editors: editors.slice()
              });
          return protectionConfig;
      }, []);
      return protectionConfig;
  }


function setSpreadsheetProtections(spreadsheet, protectionConfig) {
    spreadsheet.getSheets().forEach(function (sheet) {
        var protection = sheet.protect();
        protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors().map(function(editor) {
            return editor.getEmail();
        }));
        var currentSheetName = sheet.getName();
        var config = protectionConfig.find(function (_a) {
            var sheetName = _a.sheetName;
            return sheetName === currentSheetName;
        });
        if (config)
            protection.addEditors(config.editors);
    });
}
  function resetSpreadsheetProtections() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var protectionConfig = getProtectionConfig(spreadsheet);
  removeSpreadsheetProtections(spreadsheet);
  setSpreadsheetProtections(spreadsheet, protectionConfig);
  }
```

There is another file as well called Polyfill (and is also needed):

**Polyfill.gs**

```
// https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-array.prototype.find
if (!Array.prototype.find) {
  Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype, "find", {
    value: function(predicate) {
      // 1. Let O be ? ToObject(this value).
      if (this == null) {
        throw new TypeError('"this" is null or not defined');
      }

      var o = Object(this);

      // 2. Let len be ? ToLength(? Get(O, "length")).
      var len = o.length >>> 0;

      // 3. If IsCallable(predicate) is false, throw a TypeError exception.
      if (typeof predicate !== "function") {
        throw new TypeError("predicate must be a function");
      }

      // 4. If thisArg was supplied, let T be thisArg; else let T be undefined.
      var thisArg = arguments[1];

      // 5. Let k be 0.
      var k = 0;

      // 6. Repeat, while k < len
      while (k < len) {
        // a. Let Pk be ! ToString(k).
        // b. Let kValue be ? Get(O, Pk).
        // c. Let testResult be ToBoolean(? Call(predicate, T, « kValue, k, O »)).
        // d. If testResult is true, return kValue.
        var kValue = o[k];
        if (predicate.call(thisArg, kValue, k, o)) {
          return kValue;
        }
        // e. Increase k by 1.
        k++;
      }

      // 7. Return undefined.
      return undefined;
    },
    configurable: true,
    writable: true,
  });
}
```