# Google Sheets Scripts - Copy whole sheet protection

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using a solution [given here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52825623/2229384) to copy sheets while maintaining the protection. I have added the Google Sheets API - V4 with name Sheets.

However, it throws error -

```
GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate failed with error: Invalid requests[0].addProtectedRange: The range you're trying to exclude must be within "A".
```

After Some trial and error I found that because my protection is whole sheet except some ranges, it gives error. When I protect only few ranges, the code works fine.

Now the solution [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/86984/in-google-sheets-how-do-i-duplicate-a-sheet-along-with-its-permission/87000#87000) does duplicate sheet with the whole sheet protection. However, it's for single sheet. I need to combine these two but I am struggling.

The sheet object returned by copyTo() and Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(id) are different, the second one does not have protect() method. So I do not have a specific error here, but need solution directed towards combining two solutions. I need to duplicate multiple sheets while maintaining whole sheet protection without some ranges.

Comment: God knows why people are downvoting. I did not find the similar question anywhere else. The one mentioned in answer is for single sheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Issue:

The linked code pertains to the multiple protection ranges, not the sheet protection with exceptions. As you can see, the code included `addProtectedRange` and it conflicts with your existing protections since the code assumed you to have `Range` but instead you have `Sheet` protections which are not compatible with each other.

Use this code instead:

#### Code:

```
function duplicateSheetWithProtections() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 

  // Template sheet
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Template");
  var p = sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.SHEET)[0];

  // Output sheet, and protect the sheet by default
  var sheet2 = sheet.copyTo(ss).setName("Template Copy"); 
  var p2 = sheet2.protect();
  
  // Copy protection properties
  p2.setDescription(p.getDescription());
  p2.setWarningOnly(p.isWarningOnly());  

  if (!p.isWarningOnly()) {
    // Copy editors
    p2.removeEditors(p2.getEditors());
    p2.addEditors(p.getEditors());
    // Copy domain settings if using Apps domain
    // p2.setDomainEdit(p.canDomainEdit()); 
  }

  // Get all unprotected ranges on template
  var ranges = p.getUnprotectedRanges();
  var newRanges = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < ranges.length; i++) {
    newRanges.push(sheet2.getRange(ranges[i].getA1Notation()));
  } 

  // Unprotect them in output
  p2.setUnprotectedRanges(newRanges);
}
```

#### Output:

[image: output]

#### EDIT:

- If you want to have multiple sheets duplicated from template, then just modify the function by adding a parameter/variable as your `sheetName`. Code should be like this:

`function duplicateSheetWithProtections(sheetName) {`

and

`var sheet2 = sheet.copyTo(ss).setName(sheetName);`

- Then call the function inside a loop.

```
function main() {
  var sheetNames = ["A", "B", "C"];
  sheetNames.forEach(function (sheetName){
    duplicateSheetWithProtections(sheetName);
  });
}
```

#### Reference:

- [Scenario 1: template is a protected sheet with unprotected ranges](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/87000/260833)

Comment: Thank you @NaziA. I stumbled upon same code and was trying to implement it for bulk sheets. However, I get protect() is not a function. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: how many sheets are you planning to duplicate @SurajS? can you show your code trying to do this answer above so I can debug your issue.

Comment: I have modified my answer above and added a loop to create bulk duplicated sheets. kindly check @SurajS

Comment: 12 copies. one for each month and this need to be done multiple times. I have updated the question.

Comment: Thank you Nazia, I'll be also happy if you could find what's wrong in my code above as it'll help me understand scripts better.

Comment: Hi @SurajS, kindly join https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232926/room-for-nazia-and-surajs so we can discuss your issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232940/discussion-between-surajs-and-nazia).